How do you assign a struct variable to have a value after running a function?
I want to fetch an image Url from my Firebase storage and assign it to the User's profileImageUrl variable but it seems like I can not directly assign it in the function. Would there be a way to set something like profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString?
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseStorage

struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable{
    @DocumentID var uid: String?
    let fullname: String
    let email: String
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    
    var id: String {
        return uid ?? NSUUID().uuidString
    }
    
    var firstName: String {
        let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
        let components = formatter.personNameComponents(from: fullname)
        return components?.givenName ?? fullname
    }
    
    
    func fetchProfileImageUrl(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
        guard let uid = uid else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images/\(uid).jpg")
        storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching profile image URL: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            } else {
                completion(url?.absoluteString)
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried creating a separate model for the user but still the profileImageUrl is always nil.

You could try using mutating func fetchProfileImageUrl... and
self.profileImageUrl = url?.absoluteString just before the completion(url?.absoluteString).
